# Redis TTL issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm using Redis with GUI is Redis-commander. I'm setting to key with ttl is 2000s. But somehow ttl on redis-commander is always 5000s. I tried setting ttl with different values ​​like 1s 10s 200s but they always show on redis-commander as 5000s.

Here my cache set:

```
await this.cacheManager.set(keyRfToken, refreshToken, 2000)
```

and my redis-commander:

[image: My redis-commander]

Here my cacheModule:

```
const redisStore = require('cache-manager-redis-store').redisStore
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
@Module({
imports: [
CacheModule.register({
  isGlobal : true,
  store : redisStore,
  host : "localhost",
  port : 6379,
  
}),
```

What happening? Please help me.

Comment: Does this still happen if you call `set` on the `cacheManager`, rather than its store? So: `await this.cacheManager.set(keyRfToken, refreshToken, 2000)`

Comment: Yes, it always is 5000s